# Combine output of multiple os.walk runs

Tags: python, os.walk

I have multiple directories `dirs = [dir1, dir2, ...]`

These dirs are structured like this:

```
dir1
  subdir1
    folder1
    file1
    file2
  subdir2
dir2
  subdir1
    folder2
      file3
    file4
  subdir2
```

Note that the names of the subdirs are the same. Both dir1 and dir2 have identical named subdirectories. What I need is to print an html table that combines the files and folders from dir1 and dir2, like so:

```
subdir1
  folder1
  folder2
    file3
  file1
  file2
  file4
subdir2
```

One more caveat is that I need to know the path of each file and folder, so I can link to it.

So far I create the tree for dir1 with `os.walk` and create an html table from that, every line of which is in a list. Then I do `os.walk` for all other dirs, and for every dir, go through that list, until the basename is the same, then insert the files and folders. But this is very slow. I am sure there is a very clever, five line solution that would achieve the same.

```
def get_table(self, teams=['test1', 'test2']):
    paths = []
    table = []
    for team in teams:
        paths.append(config.basepath + '/' + team)
    for path in paths:
        if not table:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                dirs = sorted(dirs)
                files = sorted(files)
                team = self.get_team(path) # extracts the 'dir' from path
                level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
                indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
                subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
                table.append('{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(indent, os.path.basename(root), team))
                for f in files:
                    table.append('{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(subindent, f, team))
        else:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
                dirs = sorted(dirs)
                files = sorted(files)
                team = self.get_team(path)
                level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
                indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
                subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
                for idx, line in enumerate(table):
                    if os.path.basename(root) in line:
                        for f in files:
                            table.insert(idx+1, '{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(subindent, f, team))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate the extraction part from the restitution part

Extraction:

```
def process(path, d={}):
    print('initial', d)
    for i in os.scandir(path):
        if i.is_file():
            if i.name in d: raise Exception(i.path +
                            "already present")
            d[i.name] = None
        elif i.is_dir():
            if not i.name in d: d[i.name] = {}
            process(i.path, d[i.name])
    print('final', d)
    return d
```

Display:

```
def process(path, d={}):
    print('initial', d)
    for i in os.scandir(path):
        if i.is_file():
            if i.name in d: raise Exception(i.path +
                            "already present")
            d[i.name] = None
        elif i.is_dir():
            if not i.name in d: d[i.name] = {}
            process(i.path, d[i.name])
    print('final', d)
    return d
```

With the structure you proposed, it gives:

```
>>> process('dir1')
>>> d = process('dir2')
>>> print(d)
{'subdir1': {'folder2': {'file3': None}, 'file1': None, 'file2': None, 'folder1': {}, 'file4': None}, 'subdir2': {}}
>>> display(d)
subdir1
  file1
  file2
  file4
  folder1
  folder2
    file3
subdir2
```

That way, you only have to change the display part for the HTML formatting...

Comment: I think you accidentaly posted the process function twice, without the display function.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it to run with this, however, I am sure there is a better solution:

```
for path in paths:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            dirs = sorted(dirs)
            files = sorted(files)
            team = self.get_team(path)
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' ' * 4 * (level)
            subindent = ' ' * 4 * (level + 1)
            basename = os.path.basename(root)
            if firstrun:
                table.append('{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(indent, basename, team))
                coretasks[basename] = len(table) - 1
                for f in files:
                    table.append('{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(subindent, f, team))
            else:
                parsed_folders = []
                if basename in coretasks:
                    inserted_files = 0
                    for f in files:
                        table.insert(coretasks[basename] + 1, '{0}<tr class="{2}"><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>'.format(subindent, f, team))
                        inserted_files += 1
                    parsed_folders.append(basename)
                    for coretask in coretasks.keys():
                        if not coretask in parsed_folders: coretasks[coretask] += inserted_files
        firstrun = False
    print('\n'.join(table))
```